# Need some clarification on mongoose/mongodb populate command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

Hello so I am making a basic app with users and posts.

I followed the mongoose documentation on population (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html) and setup my Schemas so that the users and be connected to posts

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
password: { type: String, required: true },
email:  String,
created_at: Date,
updated_at: Date,
admin: Boolean,
posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_user : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
audioFile: { type: String, required: true },
imageFile: { type: String },
title: { type: String, required: true },
artist: { type: String, required: true },
start: { type: String, required: true },
stop: { type: String, required: true },
genre: { type: String, required: true },
tags: [{ type: String }]

});
```

---

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    Post.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
        if(!err){
            res.render('main.njk', {
                posts : allPosts,
                title : 'Title',
                isLogged : req.session.isLogged,
                user : req.session.user,
                messages : req.flash('alert')
            });
        } else { return done(err); }
    });

});
```

Thats all fine and gravy and I can run a foreach loop on allPosts to pull each one in my HTML, but when I try to think of how I am going to display all the posts with their respective users attached to each post I am unsure of how to connect the two since all the examples in the mongoose doc is just mainly for findOne.

I was thinking something like this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    Post.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
        if(!err){
            allPosts.populate('_user', ['username']);
            allPosts.exec(function (err, users){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log(users); 
            });
            res.render('main.njk', {
                posts : allPosts,
                title : 'Spaurk.net',
                isLogged : req.session.isLogged,
                user : req.session.user,
                messages : req.flash('alert')
            });
        } else { return done(err); }
    });

});
```

but that doesn't work of course.

So I was wondering if anyone with experience with this situation would be able to help me solve this.

Thanks a lot for any input.

EDIT, thanks to Daves help I was able to get the populate to work properly, I just cant pull the fields I want correctly with

```
    Post.find({}).populate('_user').exec(function(err, allPosts){
```

In my loop     {% for post in posts %}
, when I do post._user it shows the whole user schema, but when I do post._user.username it doesn't return anything. I am unsure as to why this is.

Comment: You'll need to change your query to something like this:  `Post.find({}).populate('_user').exec((err, allposts){...})`.  That will populate all `Post` documents `user` properties and return it to you as one collection of documents.

Comment: Hello Dave, thank  you for the reply and clearing the syntax up. When I call in my foreach loop post._user.username I get nothing back, but when I call post._user it gives me the whole object of the user back, i cant access each field individiaully for some reason. Thank you again for your help

Comment: are you doing the foreach on the `_user` array?

Comment: {% for post in posts %} is all i have. should I put under that too, {% for user in posts._user %}?

Comment: ahh, yes, _user is an array, so you'll have to loop through it if you want to access individual properties, or specify which object in the array you want to use like: `post._user[0].username`

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification!! It seems I dont need another loop if I just use the post._user[0].username it correctly displays the right use for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to structure a populate on a query is like this:

```
Post.find({})
    .populate('_user')
    .exec((err, allposts){...})
```

Then you will have an array of your `Posts` with the `_user` array populated.  If you need to access a property of a user, you will need to do another loop through the `_user` array or specify with use you want to use `_user[0].<property>`

Comment: Works perfectly now. Cheers!